# Hibernate: detect linked field and save an object

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I save object into database and simultaneously detect linked `topic_id` in the `grammar.topics` by `topic_name`?

```
public void updateResult(String topic_name, int userId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Beginner bgn = new Beginner();
    bgn.setUserId(userId);
    bgn.setScore(100);
    // how to detect `topic_id` here by `topic_name` from the `grammar.topics`
    bgn.setTopic_id( ... );
    session.save(bgn);
}
```

[image]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "beginner", uniqueConstraints = 
    {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "topic_id"})})
public class Beginner implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private int user_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "topic_id", nullable = false)
    private int topic_id;

    @Column(name = "score", nullable = false)
    private int score;

    //getters&setters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your method, you have not the `id` for `Topic` entity and you need it for persisting your `Beginner` entity, you must retrieve that information from the database.
If in `Topic` table , topic_name is `UNIQUE`. Easy : do a query where you retrieve the single Topic `entity` or the `topicId` with this `topicName` value.
 Ideally, you could avoid the query by keeping the `topicId` value when you retrieve the topic name information.

You could so replace `topicName` information in your processing by `topicId` information to be able to set the relation when you want to persist your `Beginner` instance.  :

```
public void updateResult(String topicId, int userId)
```

instead of

```
public void updateResult(String topic_name, int userId)
```